# Display posts with specific tags on wordpress homepage?

Tags: php, html, jquery, wordpress, tags

I'm trying to only show posts with the tag '44' or '9' on my wordpress home page.

So far I am here:

```
<?php get_header();?>

<div class="container pt-5 pb-5">

<h1><?php the_title();?></h1>

<?php

$query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag__in' => array( 44, 9 ) ) );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) :

while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();?>

    <?php the_content();?>

<?php endwhile; endif;?>

</div>

<?php get_footer();?>
```

But I can't see the posts. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I don't see anything obvious wrong with your code. Are your posts custom post types? If you use this, do you get any posts? `$query = new WP_Query( array( post_type' => 'any, 'post_status' => 'any' ) );` This will help debug whether the problem is with the code or the posts themselves.

Comment: Hey! So that is now showing all the items in my 'media' folder, and 3 of the posts?
edit: just realisng that is 10 items in total, which I'm guessing I have limited somewhere in my wordpress dashboard

Comment: Yes, you can set the posts per page in WP Admin under "Settings > Reading". OK, your `WP_Query` code is working so that means it is something to do with the args and it sounds like its to do with the tags. Now try this: `$query = new WP_Query( array( post_type' => 'any, 'post_status' => 'any', array( 'tag__in' => array( 44, 9 ) ) ) );` and if that doesn't work, it is not picking up the tags so check that are added correctly, clear your caches, resave permalinks.

Comment: It's working with this : $query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag' => '44,9' ) ); . Thank you !

Comment: That's strange - `tag__in` worked when we searched for all posts, so something else much have changed also, It would be good to know exactly what was wrong so that it will help other users who get this problem too!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query, you have specified that are looking for posts with the tags 44 or 9:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag__in' => array( 44, 9 ) ) );
```

Note that this doesn't get *all* posts with these tags - there are also other constraints in this query that are not seen here. `WP_Query` has a number of default values, so if you don't set them in your args, then it will use those. These default args include:

- `post_status` = `public` (unless the user is logged in - then `private` is also included)
- `post_type` = `post` (not that this is a specific post type and does not include all posts e.g. custom post types)

As your query isn't returning anything, and based on the debugging you've done to show that there are posts with these tags, we know that one of these default values are preventing the query from getting your posts.

1. Confirm that the posts you want to get are **published** and **public**
2. If you are using a custom post type, you need to include it to your WP_Query. If your CPT slug is `my_cpt` for example, you can include it as follows:

```
$args = array( post_type' => 'my_cpt', 
               array( 'tag__in' => array( 44, 9 ) ) );
$query = new WP_Query( $args);
```

You can also search for multiple post types in one go by using `'post_type' => array( 'post', 'my_cpt')`

FYI if you are not sure what the slug is for your post, go to the page in the WP admin that lists all the posts you are trying to get and look at the url - it will include the post type like this:

```
https://www.example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=my_cpt
```